# Angular 4 - Initialization external libs on right time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to use a ui kit (http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/components-documentation.html#checkbox-row) and it's have several js files, jquery, bootstrap, its own etc. I included them in the index.html and works well if the checkbox or other visual element is on the page at start.
But when i hide a div under ngIf with the checkboxes, and a button toggle shows this div later, it's visual element what the js files adds to it, doesn't do they job and i don't see the fancy checkboxes.
As i think, the external libs right part should be initialized when the hidden div comes visible.
How could i overcome with this issue? (i am using angular 4 with server side rendering)

Comment: Is that english?

Comment: Can you provide relevant code? Also keep in mind *ngIf doesn't hide elements, it removes them. Try binding to [hidden] instead and see if that fixes your issue,

Comment: Thanks, @miked ! The [hidden] worked, that was strange after angularjs that i didn't found the ng-show, ng-hide directives. If you make that comment as an answer, i can flag them as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i hide a div under ngIf

The `*ngIf` directive does not hide the div, it removes or adds it to the DOM which is probably why you're having initialization issues. Try binding to `[hidden]` instead.